# File unable to opened in Camera Intent

Tags: android

One of my fragments contains a simple camera application. It is supposed to take a photo and then permanently display the photo in the imageView. I am receiving a file not found error when passing in my newly created file into my Camera Intent. I am not sure why this is happening. My intent will still go through and I can take a picture but it will not save to the file. My code below.

Code:

```
package layout;

import com.tble.brgo.R;

import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.Date;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link StudentID#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class StudentID extends Fragment {
    String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    Uri mPhotoURI;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    ImageView picView;
    FloatingActionButton button;
    public StudentID() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment StudentID.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static StudentID newInstance() {
        StudentID fragment = new StudentID();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_student_id, container, false);
        picView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.idPic);
        picView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        button = (FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.picButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
        picView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.idPic);
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        picView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(sharedPref.getString("StudentID","")));
        return view;
    }
    public void takePicture(){
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                try {
                    mPhotoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPhotoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = new File(storageDir,imageFileName + ".jpg");
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK){
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("StudentID", mPhotoURI.toString());
                picView.setImageURI(mPhotoURI);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
12-19 19:09:50.238 5705-5705/com.tble.brgo W/ImageView: Unable to open content: file:///data/user/0/com.tble.brgo/files/JPEG_20161219_190950_.jpg
                                                        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.tble.brgo/files/JPEG_20161219_190950_.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:487)
                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:676)
                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:832)
                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:449)
                                                            at layout.StudentID.takePicture(StudentID.java:107)
                                                            at layout.StudentID$1.onClick(StudentID.java:78)
                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265)
                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                         Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:473)
                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:676) 
                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:832) 
                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:449) 
                                                            at layout.StudentID.takePicture(StudentID.java:107) 
                                                            at layout.StudentID$1.onClick(StudentID.java:78) 
                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5265) 
                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21534) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);`. This means that if you are lucky, you will have a picture seconds or minutes later.

You will not have the picture by the next statement, where you have `picView.setImageURI(photoURI);`.

Move `picView.setImageURI(photoURI);` into `onActivityResult()`, and call it only if you actually get a picture (i.e., result is `ACTIVITY_OK`).

Comment: no words about [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException.html)?

Comment: @Selvin: Well, that's complicated, and it wasn't really directly related to the specific problem in the question. But yes, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher, and you want to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you're going to have some work to do, whether that is using `FileProvider` or reconfiguring `StrictMode` to stop throwing `FileUriExposedException`. Ideally, we could use `FileProvider`. In reality... I'm not sure enough camera apps support `content` schemes.

Comment: *I'm not sure enough camera apps support `content` schemes*  working fine on android 2.3.X emulator ... If they are not then they are bad written. :)

Comment: This solution removes the error from the print stack trace. However, the returned result code is always RESULT_CANCELLED despite the fact I actually do take a photo on the device. I think this is still because the startActivityForResult is rejecting file photoFile that I put in as a parameter. I have updated my code to what it is now.

Comment: @Praveen: Third party apps do not have access to `getFilesDir()` of your app. Use external storage or `FileProvider`.

Comment: I have modified it to use External Storage, specifically the Pictures Directory. I am now receiving a different result code, -1. This is still some error but Im not familiar with a result code less than 0. The code is updated

Comment: @Praveen: [-1 is `RESULT_OK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK), meaning everything is fine.

Comment: After debugging it seems my ImageView is unable to load the file due to the open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) error. I have checked my manifest and I have both Read and Write External Storage Permissions. Why do I not have access?

Comment: @Praveen: Perhaps you have not requested `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` at runtime. That is required if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher and you are running on Android 6.0 or higher.

Comment: This works! Do you know why I only had to request read permissions at runtime and not write?

Comment: @Praveen: Technically, you wind up getting both, at least through Android 7.0. What the user approves is the permission group, and both `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are part of the same group. So long as you have `<uses-permission>` elements for both, if you `requestPermissions()` for one, you get the other. However, that is subject to change in future versions of Android, so I recommend you include both permissions in the `String[]` that you pass to `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks so much for your help in answering my novice questions. If possible can you take a look at this problem as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079320/external-library-negating-onclicklistener